# get curl respone encoding

Tags: php, encoding, curl

I'm using cURL to retrieve a webpage. 
What's the easiest way to get encoding of the page?
Of course I can parse response header to get charset, but I wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imo the most efficient way in this case will be:

```
$sContentType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
```